# Flash / TextField / Safari - Can't type into text field when wmode is set to transparent

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, safari

Why are text fields not catching events properly in Safari when wmode is transparent (no problems in ie/ff/chrome)? The only workarounds I've found involve sending html form field events to flash through an external interface (eg. overlaying html form on flash). Is there a graceful solution / workaround to this problem?

Edit: Swfobject embed code...

```
<script>

var swfVersionStr = "10.2.0";
var xiSwfUrlStr = "playerProductInstall.swf";
var flashvars = {};

flashvars.swfsPath = "http://domain.com/swfs/";
flashvars.initial_section = "0";

var params = {};

params.quality = "high";
params.bgcolor = "#cfc7c0";
params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
params.allowfullscreen = "true";
params.wmode = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1) ? "transparent" : "opaque";

var attributes = {};

attributes.id = "Loader";
attributes.name = "Loader";
attributes.align = "middle";

swfobject.embedSWF(
    flashvars.swfsPath + "Loader.swf", "Loader", 
    "100%", "100%", 
    swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
    flashvars, params, attributes); 

swffit.fit("Loader", 980, 726);

</script>
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you are already doing some kind of hack by overlaying forms on a flash movie. vmode will usually give you issues. Can you be more secific on what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: @The_asMan We're trying to create a simple form, only a few text fields, but we can't type in them on safari (element gains focus, but ignores keystrokes). Atm no workaround is in place.

Comment: When you say element what exactly are you referring to? An html text field? A flash text field? simplify your code and post it

Comment: @The_asMan a flash Text Input. Its not receiving key events. It seems to be a bug with the flash debugger version in safari :/.

Comment: It seems you are not the only one with this problem. Have you seen this? http://analogcode.com/p/JSTextReader/ wmode is always a nightmare to work with.

Comment: What embed method are you using? swfobject? post your embed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a known problem for a long time... I spoke to Adobe at the MAX Convention in LA and they are aware of it but no plans at the moment to fix it... sorry buddy

Comment: Will using a TLF TextField perhaps solve it? I asked someone else in the office about this and he tested for me and it worked, but he's using TLF... I'm going to go away and try that now.